# Image with stretch not displayed completely

Tags: wpf, image, scrollviewer, stretch

I would like to use a Window to display one (or optionally two) image(s) in a grid row.
This image could be quite big, so I set the Stretch property to "UniformToFill" and embed the grid into a scrollviewer.

My Image is of app. 800 x 400 px and if I try to load it into my window, it is not displayed in complete width (the horiz. scrollbar stops before the end of the image).

I would like the image(s) to fill the available window area, but to be able to scroll to see it completely. What is wrong?

Thanks for your help!

tabina

This is my code:

The .xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Wpf.Dialogs.ImageBox"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="ImageBox" Topmost="True" WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner"  Width="800" Height="600">
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" CanContentScroll="True">
  <Grid x:Name="gridImages">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Image Grid.Row="0" x:Name="img1" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
    <Image Grid.Row="1" x:Name="img2" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
  </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

The code behind:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace Wpf.Dialogs
{

public partial class ImageBox : Window
{
  public ImageBox() : this("Image", string.Empty, 800, 600)
  {
  }

  public ImageBox(string title, string image, int width, int height)
    : this(title, new string[] { image }, width, height)
  {
  }

  public ImageBox(string title, string[] images, int width, int height)
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    this.Title = title;
    this.Image = images;
  }


  public string[] Image
  {
    set
    {
      if (value != null)
      {
        var bim = CreateBitmap(value[0]);
        this.img1.Source = bim;

        if (value.Length == 2)
        {
          var bi = CreateBitmap(value[1]);

          if (bi != null)
          {
            this.img2.Source = bi;
          }
        }
        else
        {
          this.img2.Source = null;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  private BitmapImage CreateBitmap(string file)
  {
    if (File.Exists(file))
    {
      var bmp = new BitmapImage();
      bmp.BeginInit();
      bmp.UriSource = new Uri(file);
      bmp.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
      bmp.EndInit();

      return bmp;
    }
    else
    {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can't use ScrollViewer and  at the same time with Stretch="UniformToFill". Use Grid and Stretch="UniformToFill" or ScrollViewer and Grid.

Comment: So how could I get the image(s) to fill the grid rows (like zoom to fit) and at the same time be able to scroll to see all parts of the image(s)?